# Javascript for-loop freezes the browser, without syntax error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, freeze

I have problems with a line of code in javascript. I have done a funtcion:

```
function evvalt(valtoztat){
    for(i=0;i<12;i++) naptar(valtoztat);
}
```

If I do this way, then the browser freezes out. There is no problem with the naptar(function) it works perfectly. The interesting side of this problem the next:

```
function evvalt(valtoztat){
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
    naptar(valtoztat);
}
```

There is no problem this code.. :O
I would like to know what the problem is.

Thank you for your assistence,
 David

Comment: You got an infinite loop that's what happens..

Comment: What happens when you do `for(var i=0; ...`?

Comment: Try not to use the shorthand syntax also, use brackets { }

Comment: How? If the naptar() function works well, using it in a for loop which do the naptar() function in one line, why could cause infinite loop?

Comment: Thank you the `code`for(var i=0; ...` works well!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not declared the variable `i` as a local variable it is being treated as a global variable and it is likely that something in your `naptar()` function is also changing the value of `i` causing an infinite loop.

Add `var` in front front of the use of `i` like this to make it a local variable:

```
function evvalt(valtoztat){
    for(var i=0;i<12;i++) naptar(valtoztat);
}
```

And, also look in `naptar()` for a place where you are using `i` without declaring it as a local variable (or in any functions that `naptar()` calls).  You should ALWAYS declare local variables with `var` within the function so they do not become implicit globals.

Even better, starting using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) in Javascript where creating an accidental global like this becomes an error rather than a silent bug.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This solved the problem :)
I do my first things in this language and I haven't know that. I had written everyi for-loop variable ( there weren't any written as you said).

Answer (score 0):

you are poluting global space so there is a chance that you change your 'i' somewhere else.

rather do:

```
for (var i = 0, i < .. , i++) {..
```

if you do the for loop the same way somewhere else no wonder that it's not working.